# If $T,S\in\text{Hom}(V,V)$ and $\det(ST)=0$ why does this mean that the determinant of $S$ or $T$ is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant

> If $T,S\in\text{Hom}(V,V)$ and $ST$ is singular why does this mean that $S$ or $T$ is singular?

As far as I understand $ST$ is a composition of linear maps.

We know that there's a matrix representation for the linear map according to some basis $B$.

So $\det([ST]_B)=0$. Why can we deduce from that either $[S]_B$ or $[T]_B$ have zero determinants?

I'm aware of the property of determinant that $\det(AB)=\det A \cdot \det B$ but $AB$ is matrix multiplication but in my example $[ST]_B$ is the matrix resulting from composition of linear maps.

Please explain the determinant case and not other proof methods.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to mention that composition of linear maps (on finite-dimensional spaces) is exactly the same as matrix multiplication after a choice of bases.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Is this a simple proof or there's a theorem for this?

Comment: It's straightforward once you know how to assign a matrix to a linear map w.r.t. bases in both the domain and target, just write down what the product of matrices does with a coordinate vector and compare with the action of the composition on the same vector.

Comment: How do you even define the determinant of a linear operator without relating to matrices? (Sure, it can be done, but if you had used that level of abstraction, you would have known immediately that determinants of f.d. linear operators are multiplicative.)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I did define $[ST]_B$ to be  matrix representation of a linear map according to $B$. Let me know if this not explicit enough.

Comment: Right, I see. And did you know that $[ST]_B=[S]_B\,[T]_B$?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen do you mean that $[ST]_B=[S]_B\cdot [T]_B$?

Comment: Yes I do. If you can write composition of linear maps by juxtaposition (without any operator), then you might do the same foto matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of an endomorphism is defined as the determinant by its matrix representation with respect to some basis $B$. You can then prove, that this is invariant under basis transformation. With this knowledge we see: $ST$ is singular implies $\det (ST)=0$, which is 
$$0=\det (ST)=\det([ST]_B)=\det ([S]_B)\cdot\det ([T]_B)$$
From that we can conclude $\det ([S]_B)=0$ or $\det ([T]_B)=0$, thus $S$ or $T$ singular.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that $V$ is finite-dimensional.

If $\det(ST)=0$ then $ST$ is not injective. Therefore $T$ is not injective (and then $\det(T)=0$) or it is injective. But then it is a bijection and so, since $ST$ is not injective, $S$ is not injective and therefore $\det(S)=0$.